# Vue props become null on $router.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to route back on the 2nd page like this.
This is the 3rd page

```
 <v-btn text small @click="$router.go(-1)">
   <v-icon>fas fa-arrow-left</v-icon>
 </v-btn>
```

This is my App.vue

```
<keep-alive :max="40">
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

This are my 2nd page props.

```
props: {
    abc: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return null;
      }
    },
    xyz: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
```

Now the 2nd page has props in it. Now when i route back from 3rd page the props in the previous 
component is set to null.
Is there a way to handle this props from being setting it to null on routing back.

Comment: are the props to that component are passed from route? Please post some relevant code for component. or better add broken example in codesandbox or jsfiddle.

Comment: this usefull? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Comment: @Pradeepb  I have edited the question. Do have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Props works from parent to child only, if you are navigating back to that component having props via non parent then props will always be null, in this scenario you can use localStorage or try using https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Comment: I have use keep alive in my App.vue file. But still the props are not cached.

Answer (score 0):

You should use keep-alive to fix this problem, or instead use vuex
to pass the data to the route, because when you are going back your route doesn't have any passed props, because it received it from another component our route,

vuex well make global state management that will contain your data and you can access it from anywhere